# HTTP request from Angular to Docker Engine API (Progress Output - Pull Image)

Tags: angular, docker, http, httpresponse

I am writing an Angular application to manage my docker containers/images etc.

The [Docker Engine Api v1.39](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.39/) is available via HTTP.

I got a problem with a http request "pull an image" [(documentation here)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/examples/#pull-an-image).

I wan't to Pull (Download) a image and show the progress output in my angular app. I created a request with curl which works fine and prints the progress to the stdout. With angular i can't get the progress.

**Curl request:**

> curl -u user:pass -X POST
>   "http://192.168.1.3:2376/v1.39/images/create?fromImage=10.0.149.224:5000/500:0280"

**Output:**

```
{"status":"Pulling from 500","id":"0280"}
{"status":"Pulling fs layer","progressDetail":{},"id":"e12b1fe81418"}
{"status":"Downloading","progressDetail":{"current":534865,"total":1690342827},"progress":"[\u003e                                                  ]  534.9kB/1.69GB","id":"e12b1fe81418"}
{"status":"Downloading","progressDetail":{"current":8221841,"total":1690342827},"progress":"[\u003e                                                  ]  8.222MB/1.69GB","id":"e12b1fe81418"}
{"status":"Downloading","progressDetail":{"current":17691793,"total":1690342827},"progress":"[\u003e                                                  ]  17.69MB/1.69GB","id":"e12b1fe81418"}
{"status":"Downloading","progressDetail":{"current":26023889,"total":1690342827},"progress":"[\u003e                                                  ]  26.02MB/1.69GB","id":"e12b1fe81418"}
{"status":"Downloading","progressDetail":{"current":34936785,"total":1690342827},"progress":"[=\u003e                                                 ]  34.94MB/1.69GB","id":"e12b1fe81418"}
....
....
{"status":"Pull complete","progressDetail":{},"id":"e12b1fe81418"}
{"status":"Digest: sha256:d3d30b514d3592e6df8d3196e365ef1a5128f6a20747a87a889f8de673da476a"}
```

**Angular:**

registry.service.ts

```js
  public downloadImage(): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', `http://192.168.1.3:2376/v1.39/images/create?fromImage=10.0.149.224:5000/500:0280`, {
      reportProgress: true
    });

    return this.http.request(req);
  }
```

registry.component.ts

```js
public downloadImage(): void {
    this.dockerRegistryService.downloadImage()
    .subscribe(event => {

      // progress
      if (event.type === HttpEventType.DownloadProgress) {
        // console.log(event, event);
        // event.loaded = bytes transfered
        // event.total = "Content-Length", set by the server
        // const percentage = 100 / event.total * event.loaded;
        // console.log(percentage);
        console.log('event');
      }

      // finished
      if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
        console.log(event.body);
      }

    });
```

**Output:**
full log @pastebin(https://pastebin.com/uq8VQNa0)

```
ERROR 
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://192.168.1.3:2376/v1.39/images/create?fromImage=10.0.149.224:5000/500:0280", ok: false, …}
headers: HttpHeaders
normalizedNames: Map(0)
[[Entries]]
No properties
size: (...)
__proto__: Map
lazyUpdate: null
lazyInit: () => {…}
__proto__: Object
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
url: "http://192.168.1.3:2376/v1.39/images/create?fromImage=10.0.149.224:5000/500:0280"
ok: false
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
message: "Http failure during parsing for http://192.168.1.3:2376/v1.39/images/create?fromImage=10.0.149.224:5000/500:0280"
error:
error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 43 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:37027:51) at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:413:35) at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:74235:33) at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:412:40) at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:181:51) at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:494:38) at invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:1609:18) at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:1646:25)
stack: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 43↵    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)↵    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:37027:51)↵    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:413:35)↵    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:74235:33)↵    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:412:40)↵    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:181:51)↵    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:494:38)↵    at invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:1609:18)↵    at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:1646:25)"
message: "Unexpected token { in JSON at position 43"
__proto__: Error
constructor: ƒ SyntaxError()
name: "SyntaxError"
message: ""
toString: ƒ toString()
__proto__: Object
text: "{"status":"Pulling from 500","id":"0280"}
↵{"status":"Pulling fs layer","progressDetail":{},"id":"e12b1fe81418"}
↵{"status":"Downloading","progressDetail":{"current":547177,"total":1690342827},"progress":"[\u003e                                                  ]  547.2kB/1.69GB","id":"e12b1fe81418"}
↵{"status":"Downloading","progressDetail":{"current":5529697,"total":1690342827},"progress":"[\u003e                                                  ]   5.53MB/1.69GB","id":"e12b1fe81418"}
↵{"status":"Downloading","progressDetail":{"current":12214369,"total":1690342827},"progress":"[\u003e                                                  ]  12.21MB/1.69GB","id":"e12b1fe81418"}
↵{"status":"Downloading","progressDetail":{"current":20570209,"total":1690342827},"progress":"[\u003e                                                  ]  20.57MB/1.69GB","id":"e12b1fe81418"}
↵{"status":"Downloading","progressDetail":{"current":30583673,"total":1690342827},"progress":"[\u003e                                                  ]  30.58MB/1.69GB","id":"e12b1fe81418"}
↵{"status":"Downloading","progressDetail":{"current":40053625,"total":1690342827},"progress":"[=\u003e                                                 ]  40.05MB/1.69GB","id":"e12b1fe81418"}
↵{"status":"Downloading","progressDetail":{"current":47295353,"total":1690342827},"progress":"[=\u003e                                                 ]   47.3MB/1.69GB","id":"e12b1fe81418"}
↵{"status":"Downloading","progressDetail":{"current":57879417,"total":1690342827},"progress":"[=\u003e                                                 ...
....
....
↵{"status":"Digest: sha256:d3d30b514d3592e6df8d3196e365ef1a5128f6a20747a87a889f8de673da476a"}
↵{"status":"Status: Downloaded newer image for 10.0.149.224:5000/500:0280"}
↵"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

The http request "works" (it pulls the image and status is 200) but the request does not recognize any event and gives me no output while pulling the image. It just comes back, when the whole request finished and there is just an error while the http client tries to parse the multiple json returns.

**Update:** 
Trying with XMLHttpRequest:
It's my first time working with XMLHttpRequest so maybe i have done something wrong. After reading a little bit i tried to return an Observable with a "XHR" inside the callback. But that doesn't work either. My observable doesn't change until the full download is finished.

registry.service.ts

```js
public downloadImage(): Observable<Object[]> {

      return Observable.create(observer => {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('POST', `http://192.168.1.3:2376/v1.39/images/create?fromImage=10.0.149.224:5000/500:0280`, true);
      xhr.onprogress = () => {
        observer.next();
        console.log('test');
      };
      xhr.onreadystatechange =  (Evt) => {
        if (xhr.readyState === 3) {
          observer.next();
          console.log('progress');
      }

        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            observer.complete();
            console.log('finished');
        }
      };
      xhr.send();
    });      
}
```

Comment: After reading a bit into it, I discovered that this should be possible with a XMLHttpRequest. example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/progress_event
However angular abstracts this and uses either fetch() or the XMLHttpRequest, depending on the browser. Can you try using XMLHttpRequest directly, without the HttpClinet abstraction, and see if this works? It is kinda hard to test it, because I couldn't find a mock library which provides progress events.